# Return a Value from jQgrid EditURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a **jqgrid** with `ajax data` that for editing I have choose inline edit with some `editURl` that pointed to a webService.

It works fine but how can I have a return value then .

I mean after edit, how can I send some value to the page ???

Thanx

Comment: Thanks LOL for your edit , I was a bit sleepy ;-)

Comment: I create a XML for send to another page, i take date like that `$('#GRID').jqGrid('getRowData', rowid)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've only just come across this question, and I was hoping you had the answer :)  But I worked it out myself and can now give you an answer to solve this.

You can use the `successfunc` event attached to the `jqGrid('saveRow', ...)` call.

Assume in your controller where you have implemented the `editURL` for your jqGrid you return a JSON object (this is in MVC4):

```
JsonResult retVal = Json(new { someArray, someProperty });
return retVal;
```

Now in your call to save the row in jQuery, you can access those JSON properties:

```
$("#OrgUnitTableGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', lastSel, 
    {
    successfunc: function (response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        var thisArray = data.someArray;
        var thisProperty = data.someProperty;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)